# Change xscreensaver lock option command

Tags: command-line, fedora, terminal, screensaver

How could I change the lock option for the `xscreensaver` from the command line? 
Been looking around and couldn't find anything about it. 
`xscreensaver-command -lock` will lock it right away, which is not what I'm looking for. 
I'm using Fedora 14.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what it is you _are_ looking for/attempting to do?

Comment: @jasonwryan I would like to be able to change some options (especially the lock) without opening the GUI. To call it from a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't been able to find an actual command to change the `lock` feature, but in the configuration file `.xscreensaver`, located in the home folder, I've found the value of lock: `lock: False`

In order to modify its value, I can change the value in the config file by using the command:

```
sed -i 's/\(lock:\t\t\).*/\1False/' /home/username/.xscreensaver
```

`False` can be replaced with `True` based on the requirements.